# onClick passing in tests, but failing when physically clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, styled-components

This is my `Accordion` component

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import ArrowTemplate from "./ArrowTemplate";
import ContentTemplate from "./ContentTemplate";

class Accordion extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {isAccordionExpanded: false};
        this.foldAccordion = this.foldAccordion.bind(this);
        this.expandAccordion = this.expandAccordion.bind(this);
    }

    expandAccordion() {
        console.log(1);
        this.setState({isAccordionExpanded: true});
    }

    foldAccordion() {
        console.log(2);
        this.setState({isAccordionExpanded: false});
    }

    render() {
        const {state} = this;
        const {isAccordionExpanded} = state;

        if (isAccordionExpanded === false) {
            return (
                <Fragment>
                    <ArrowTemplate
                        aria={`aria-expanded="true"`}
                        onClick={this.expandAccordion}
                        direction={'down'}
                        color={'black'}
                        styles={'background:yellow'}
                    />
                </Fragment>
            );
        } else if (isAccordionExpanded === true) {
            return (
                <Fragment>
                    <ArrowTemplate
                        aria={`aria-expanded="true"`}
                        onClick={this.foldAccordion}
                        color={'black'}
                        direction={'up'}
                    />
                    <ContentTemplate/>
                </Fragment>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default Accordion;
```

this is the `ArrowTemplate`

```
import React from "react";
import BlackDownArrowSVG from './svgs/black-down-arrow.svg';
import WhiteDownArrowSVG from './svgs/white-down-arrow.svg';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

ArrowTemplate.propTypes = {
    color: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    direction: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    styles: PropTypes.string,
    aria: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

function ArrowTemplate(props) {
    const {color, direction, styles, aria} = props;
    const StyledArrowTemplate = styled.img.attrs({
        src: color.toLowerCase() === "black" ? BlackDownArrowSVG : WhiteDownArrowSVG,
        aria,
    })`
        ${direction.toLowerCase() === "up" ? "translate: rotate(180deg)" : ""}
        ${styles}
`;
    return <StyledArrowTemplate/>;
}

export default ArrowTemplate;
```

And here are my related tests

```
describe("<Accordion/>",
    () => {
        let wrapper;
        beforeEach(
            () => {
                wrapper = shallow(
                    <Accordion/>
                );
            }
        );
        it('should have one arrow at start',
            function () {
                expect(wrapper.find(ArrowTemplate)).toHaveLength(1);
            }
        );
        it('should change state onClick',
            function () {
                wrapper.find(ArrowTemplate).simulate("click");
                expect(wrapper.state().isAccordionExpanded).toEqual(true);
            }
        );
        it('should call FoldAccordionMock onClick',
            function () {
                wrapper.setState({isAccordionExpanded: true});
                wrapper.find(ArrowTemplate).simulate("click");
                expect(wrapper.state().isAccordionExpanded).toEqual(false);
            }
        );
        it('should display content if isAccordionExpanded = true',
            function () {
                wrapper.setState({isAccordionExpanded: true});
                expect(wrapper.find(ContentTemplate).exists()).toEqual(true);
            }
        );
        it('should hide content if isAccordionExpanded = false',
            function () {
                expect(wrapper.find(ContentTemplate).exists()).toEqual(false);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

So the problem is that when I tun the tests .simulate(click) seems to work, and all tests pass. But when I click the component myself, nothing happens. Not even a console log. Changing the onClick to `onClick={()=>console.log(1)}` doesn't work either. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: You have to actually write `onClick` on your element. Try this, `<StyledArrowTemplate onClick={props.onClick}/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StyledArrowTemplate` inner component does not know anything about `onClick`.
 `ArrowTemplate` doesn't know what `onClick` means, it's just another arbitrary prop to it.

But, if you do as @ravibagul91 said in their comment, you should pass down onClick again, `StyledArrowTemplate` might know what `onClick` means.

So just add `<StyledArrowTemplate onClick={props.onClick}/>`

Answer (score 1):

**Accordion Component**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import ArrowTemplate from "./ArrowTemplate";
import ContentTemplate from "./ContentTemplate";

class Accordion extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isAccordionExpanded: false };
  }

  toggleAccordian = () => {
    console.log(1);
    this.setState({ isAccordionExpanded: !isAccordionExpanded });
  };

  render() {
    const { state } = this;
    const { isAccordionExpanded } = state;

    if (isAccordionExpanded) {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <ArrowTemplate
            aria={`aria-expanded="true"`}
            onClick={() => this.toggleAccordian()}
            color={"black"}
            direction={isAccordionExpanded ? "up" : "down"}
            styles={`background:{isAccordionExpanded ? 'yellow' : ''}`}
          />
          <ContentTemplate />
        </Fragment>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default Accordion;
```